# how to call a Webservice from C++ project?

Tags: c++, web-services, visual-studio-2015

I have one C++ project, I dont know how to call APIs from the projects and take response on that. is there any packages or documentation available for the implementation?
 Please help me! Thanks in advance.

Comment: please read the description of the `api` tag. It quite nicely explains what it the problem with your question

Comment: "api" is way to broad there are *lots* of ways to call an API. Is it another dll? A webservice? RPC?

Comment: You have to be a lot more specific if you want an answer.

Comment: Maybe show a specific example of a specific function you are having trouble calling?

Comment: @ nvoigt sir webservice. sir can you give me your skype id .please ping me .my id prince tomy

Comment: i dont know how to call apis from my c++ projects.please help me

Comment: @user463035818 ok sir

Answer (score 2):

i have found one solution .if use cpprestsdk from nuget we can able to call apis from c++ project.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/cpprestsdk/

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/wiki/Getting-Started-Tutorial .go this link to get the complete tutorials and documentations.